# Is there a macOS equivalent of the Windows "call" command?

Tags: windows, macos

I know that in windows when you access another batch file from a batch file, you need to use the CALL command to return control to parent process otherwise control is passed to the batch file being executed.

So in windows you would do

```
call npm install
echo "test"
```

If you don't use 'call' in front of the npm install, the echo is never going to show.

Real case scenario where it does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd project
npm run serve

echo test
```

In this case, the test never shows up.

Is there a MacOS equivalent for the "call" command?

Comment: Just run the other script normally; it runs as a subprocess, and when it exits the "calling" script will just naturally continue.

Comment: Macs use `bash` shell, the same as Linux computers, UNIX computers and supercomputers. Try Googling *"bash tutorial"*. Windows use the awful BATCH files, Powershell thing, CMD32 and Command Prompt - try not to think how to make a Mac as awful as Windows. In `bash` you just run `npm install` and your prompt will come back afterwards and you can continue.

Comment: I modified the post with a real case scenario that doesn't work

Comment: Presumably that happens because `npm run serve` is still running. So you likely want to run it in the background in parallel using `npm run serve &`

Comment: If I add the & then it basically skips the line and goes straight to echo. I can't seem to find it in the activity manager under processes (since you mentioned that it runs in the background). I would like to see it in the terminal since I want to see errors/warning as well. I also use zsh so my next line is not echo, is 'tab', which is supposed to open another tab and start doing something else. That also doesn't work...